# Even after SBT Assembly plugin, I get main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0

Tags: scala, sbt

I added a file called plugins.sbt to my /project folder. I added the following line to this file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

In my build.scala I added the following line

```
object CoreBuild extends Build {
   import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys._
```

I did a `sbt assembly` I got a large jar file which I scp'ed to my target server.

Target server has

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

when I say `java -jar ./foo.jar com.abhi.Foo 10`

I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

But I added the assembly plugin....

Comment: Did you check the jar file if it actually contains the Scala standard library? Did you use `autoScalaLibrary := false` in your build?

Comment: no I don't see that setting anywhere.

Comment: assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = `true`, includeDependency = true), `includeScala` set to false by mistake?

Comment: Please post the entire `build.sbt`